# How can you index a variable inside a pandas query expression?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe `wins` using a loop. I have found that you can pass a variable through the `query()` expression with `@` but I have not figured out how to index the variable, which in this case is the list of `seasons`.

```
df = {index: ["team1", "team2", etc], "season1": [team1_wins, team2_wins, etc], "season2": [team1_wins, team2_wins, etc], etc}
wins_df = pd.DataFrame(df.query('season=="2008/2009"').result.value_counts())
#the above line creates the dataframe with the first column.

for i in range(1,8):  # there are 8 seasons and we have already done the first one.
    seasons = df1.season.unique().tolist()
    i = 1
    wins_df[str(seasons[i])] = df1.query('season == @seasons[i]').result.value_counts()
    i+=1

wins_df
```

Returns: `UndefinedVariableError: name 'i' is not defined`

---

## Update

As per the comment below, the query does allow indexing if `format()` is used. However, only one column is iterated and its values are all `NaN`.

Comment: kindly share some sample data, with expected output

Comment: Will `query` take a formatted string as an argument: `'season == @{}'.format(seasons[i])`?

Comment: @Andrew - thanks, I've updated the question in light of your comment.

Comment: I didn't actually mention the input/output, that was @sammywemmy. I suggest you refer to this for a good guide for writing a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The input information you've provided doesn't allow someone to replicate your issue. Did you try using a formatted string as I suggested?